# How do I turn setTimeouts to chainable plugins?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
showElem('.match');

setTimeout(function() {
    showElem('.player');

    setTimeout(function() {
        showElem('.score');

    }, inSpeed);
}, inSpeed);
```

This code calls the following function:

```
function showElem(elem) {
    $(elem).removeClass('fast');
    $(elem).addClass('display');
}
```

I would like to be replace the first piece of code with:

```
showElem('.match').delay(inSpeed).showElem('.player').delay(inSpeed).showElem('.score');
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Use [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue).

Comment: @zzzzBov `queue` has never worked for me.

Comment: Then you're probably not using it properly. I've added an answer to elaborate on how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) method to chain ordered asynchronous code that has no need of fail conditions.

When you start needing to handle errors, then promises are applicable, but in this case they're significantly overkill and get in the way of jQuery's native methods.

Your initial code of

```
showElem('.match').delay(inSpeed).showElem('.player').delay(inSpeed).showElem('.score');
```

isn't exactly compatible with jQuery without significant modifications, but it can be simplified to make use of jQuery's native functions relatively easily:

```
//pick an element that the queue will be managed on
$('body')
  .queue(showElem('.match'))
  .delay(inSpeed)
  .queue(showElem('.player'))
  .delay(inSpeed)
  .queue(showElem('.score'));
```

Now that it's written in a conforming manner, the hard part is to actually define the `showElem` function.

By its usage it needs to take a selector parameter

```
function showElem(selector) {
```

And it needs to return a function for the queue:

```
  return function (next) {
```

And when the queued function executes it needs to call your method:

```
    $(selector)
      .removeClass('fast')
      .addClass('display');
```

and because it's queued, it needs to call `dequeue`, which is what the `next` parameter does on the inner function:

```
    next();
```

---

All together it looks like:

```
function showElem(selector) {
  return function (next) {
    $(selector)
      .removeClass('fast')
      .addClass('display');
    next();
  };
}

//pick an element that the queue will be managed on
$('body')
  .queue(showElem('.match'))
  .delay(inSpeed)
  .queue(showElem('.player'))
  .delay(inSpeed)
  .queue(showElem('.score'));
```

Comment: This is indeed the better way to go.

Comment: What makes this way better than using promises?

Comment: The simplicity of the code. jQuery has everything in place for asynchronously executing the delayed tasks through its queueing mechanism. No more need of your own `delay` function.

Comment: Is there a way to have two different queues that run concurrently?

Comment: @JasonAxelrod, yes, pick literally any other element, or alternatively use an object literal if you don't want your queue to be tied directly to any elements.

Answer (score 1):

With the syntax you suggest it is not possible, because for that code would have to run synchronous, while `setTimeout` callbacks are asynchronous.

You could however do something similar with promises, using E6:

```js
var inSpeed = 1000;

showElem('.match')
    .then( _ => delay(inSpeed))
    .then( _ => showElem('.player'))
    .then( _ => delay(inSpeed))
    .then( _ => showElem('.score'));

function delay(inSpeed) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, inSpeed);
    });
}

function showElem(elem) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        $(elem).removeClass('fast');
        $(elem).addClass('display');
        resolve();
    });
}
```

```css
.fast { border: 2px solid red }
.display { background: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='match fast'>match</div>
<div class='player fast'>player</div>
<div class='score fast'>score</div>
```

#### non ES6 solution

This uses the jQuery `Deferred` method and `bind`:

```js
var inSpeed = 1000;

showElem('.match')
    .then(delay.bind(null, inSpeed))
    .then(showElem.bind(null, '.player'))
    .then(delay.bind(null, inSpeed))
    .then(showElem.bind(null, '.score'));

function delay(inSpeed) {
    var prom = new $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(prom.resolve, inSpeed);
    return prom;
}

function showElem(elem) {
    var prom = new $.Deferred();
    $(elem).removeClass('fast');
    $(elem).addClass('display');
    prom.resolve();
    return prom;
}
```

```css
.fast { border: 2px solid red }
.display { background: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='match fast'>match</div>
<div class='player fast'>player</div>
<div class='score fast'>score</div>
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working for me. The first `showElem('.match')` runs (its an animation with CSS3), but then nothing happens after.

Comment: Maybe your browser does not support ES6 fully. Internet Explorer?

Comment: Ok, I had just finished writing an alternative which does not depend on ES6 features. I have added it anyway to my answer.

Comment: Which is the better version to use? The jQuery or the ES6?

Comment: If your application is to be used on older browsers or Internet Explorer, then jQuery/non-ES6 is the better choice for now. If not, then I would certainly choose ES6.

Comment: promises for queuing is a bad choice that adds significant verbosity to something that should otherwise be very simple.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod, please consider accepting zzzzBov's answer instead of mine (if that works for you). I agree that jQuery's queue results in much simpler code, so neither promises nor a delay function have to be created.